# How to listen when a mouse moves out of the VGroup Container or TitleWindow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a popup window. In that popup window, when a user clicks a button and moves out of the popup window, the event should stop. How can I achieve this in flex?

Simply to say, if a mouse moves from the title window or any other container to the outside of the window or component, I want to listen to that event.

I tried with focus out but that fires only when user clicks or changes the component. I also tried with the mouse out event, it also didn't work for me.

Could any one please tell the solution on how to listen for the event when a user moves a mouse from inside a component to the outside of the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the rollOut event: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:rollOut

> The mouseOut event is dispatched each time the mouse leaves the area
>   of any child object of the display object container, even if the mouse
>   remains over another child object of the display object container.
>   This is different behavior than the purpose of the rollOut event,
>   which is to simplify the coding of rollover behaviors for display
>   object containers with children. When the mouse leaves the area of a
>   display object or the area of any of its children to go to an object
>   that is not one of its children, the display object dispatches the
>   rollOut event.